# How do I use other voices when using MaryTTS embed?

Tags: java, marytts

I want to use MaryTTS embed in my Java application. I have downloaded the jars and put them in my classpath. I can successfully run this test:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MaryInterface marytts = new LocalMaryInterface();
        Set<String> voices = marytts.getAvailableVoices();
        marytts.setVoice(voices.iterator().next());
        AudioInputStream audio = marytts.generateAudio("Hello world.");
        AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer(audio);
        player.start();
        player.join();
    }
```

The problem is that the only voice available is `cmu-slt-hsmm`, which makes sense because that's the only `voice-` jar I have in the classpath. However, I cannot find anywhere other jars for other voices, which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong because the Mary GUI can use other voices just fine.

How do I use other voices when using MaryTTS embed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find or create new voice jar and add this voice jar in your libs. MaryTTS does this itself using the component-installer, but i prefere to download jars manualy from official website.

Here is [the list of all available voices](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/blob/master/download/marytts-components.xml). So, lets suppose you want to add `voice-dfki-spike-hsmm`. Find apropriate name in `marytts-components.xml` and link will usually look something like this: `http://mary.dfki.de/download/5.1/voice-dfki-spike-hsmm-5.1.zip`. Now you can easily unzip and put this voice to your project libs next to maryTTS source.

> **Demo**
>
> ```
> Set<String> voices = maryTTS.getAvailableVoices();
> for(String v : voices){
>     System.out.println("Voice available: " + v);
> }
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> Voice available: cmu-slt-hsmm
> Voice available: voice-dfki-spike-hsmm
> ```

If you use maryTTS GUI you probably already have all voices somewere on your hard drive. This article may help you to find them: http://myrobotlab.org/content/marytts-multi-language-support

PS. **TTS voices themselves have individual licenses**, so don't forget to look at it in `marytts-components.xml`. Usually Creative Commons, but depending on the voice's license, it may or may not be used commercially.

Comment: What is the correct folder for voices when I use not Mary HTTP server but Mary as a Java library?