# Marytts export voice to executable jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, artifacts, marytts

I am currently trying to use marytts in my project. Now I am trying to export my project to an executable jar file. The problem is I always get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such voice: bits3-hsmm

In IntelliJ everything works fine, the error only occurs when executing the exported jar file. I added the dependencies as shown in this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wthwy.png)

The marytts interface is working correctly only the voice makes troubles. A am using an downloaded version of the voice and marytts and they should be included in my exported .jar file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766835/how-to-add-marytts-voice-jar-file-to-my-own-jar-load-from-folder-in-intellij and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932491/how-do-i-use-other-voices-when-using-marytts-embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a product of [IDEA-240253](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240253) (and related [IDEA-116209](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116209)).

> IDE should be able to handle this automatically, but currently it isn't implemented.
>
> You may keep separate JAR files and add them to the classpath of your JAR via Class-Path attribute in MANIFEST.MF file.